# Import code from multiple directories in Rust

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Apologies, if it's a duplicate questions. I looked online / stackoverflow and I couldn't find the answer. I want to import modules from different folders / files in Rust.

The structure of my files/ folders is the following:

```
src/
  test_1/
     mod.rs <- inside here I have put: pub mod a, and pub mod b
     a.rs
     b.rs
  tes_2/ 
     mod.rs <- inside here I have put: pub mod a1, and pub mod b1
     a1.rs
     b1.rs
  test_3/
     mod.rs<- inside here I have put: pub mod a2, and pub mod b2
     a2.rs
     b2.rs
```

I want to share code I have in `a.rs` with `a1.rs` and `a2.rs` or the code I have in `b2.rs` with `a.rs`.

I have tried to add mod and use inside the files, I have also try many examples online but nothing worked.

Can you please help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi there! Are you using Cargo? Do you have a `src/lib.rs` or `src/main.rs`? Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26388861/2408867) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45519176/2408867) Q&A? Do they help?

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt you comment helped a lot, please see my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking online, and after Lukas comment, I found the solution. I will try to summarise it here.

I had to create a new file named lib.rs outside of the folders:

```
src/
  test_1/
     mod.rs <- inside here I have put: pub mod a, and pub mod b
     a.rs
     b.rs
  test_2/ 
     mod.rs <- inside here I have put: pub mod a1, and pub mod b1
     a1.rs
     b1.rs
  test_3/
     mod.rs<- inside here I have put: pub mod a2, and pub mod b2
     a2.rs
     b2.rs
  lib.rs
```

Inside this file, I added the following code:

```
pub mod test_1
pub mod test_2
pub mod test_3
```

And it worked! I can now import code from different files using the `use crate` command:

Example:
`use create::test_1::a1::function_name;`