# Local crate in Rust

Tags: rust, local, crate

I am currently learning Rust, and for that purpose I wanted to create my own crate and use it. However, Rust can't find this crate.

I have the following file structure:

```
├───minimal
│    ├───Cargo.toml
│   └───src
│       └───main.rs
└───util
    └───win
        ├───Cargo.toml
        └───src
            └───lib.rs
```

In folder *minimal* I have my main project. It looks like this:

#### *Cargo.toml*

```
[package]
name = "minimal"
version = "0.1.0"
[dependecies]
win = { path = "../util/win"}
```

#### *main.rs*

```
extern crate win; // ERROR: "Can't find crate for 'win' rustc(E0463)"
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, World!");
}
```

My library in folder *win* looks like this:

#### File *Cargo.toml*

```
[package]
name = "win"
version = "0.1.0"
```

#### File *lib.rs*

```
pub type TestType = String;
```

My first assumption was that I somehow had a mistake in specifying the path in the dependency of the *Cargo.toml* file. So I tried to wiggle it around a bit, but it does not seem to work.

Rust reports

> can't find crate for 'win' rustc(E0463)

I feel like I am making a very basic error here, however, when looking at similar questions (e.g., *[How do I "use" or import a local Rust file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45519176/how-do-i-use-or-import-a-local-rust-file)*) I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Have you tried with an absolute path to see if that works?

Comment: I have tried it, yes - unfortunately it didn't work. Do I need to compile my library in a specific way for this to work?

Comment: Don't think so... I just replicated your setup and can't get the same error. Another thing to try could be to use the 2018 edition, though I doubt it will matter.

Comment: Just to check, you are using `cargo` to build/run this right? I.e. Running `cargo run` in the minimal directory

Comment: I use `cargo run` to run this, yes.I installed rust from here: https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install and I run it from visual studio code in windows 10. (I get the same error if I use the cmd-prompt directly.) Strange that it works out of the box for you.

Comment: @user2089648 It works for me too. No errors.

Comment: Have you created any additional files except the four I use?

Comment: @user2089648 No additional files. Mine looks just like yours.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After having a good night's sleep and looking at this problem again, I have managed to find the error. 
I used `[dependecies]` instead of `[dependencies]` in the *Cargo.toml* file.

On the one hand, I feel kind of dumb for this error, but on the other hand I now know that Cargo will not warn about unknown tags in the TOML file.

Comment: I like the addition of how you feel about the result. Refreshing and wholesome.