# How to import file in rust?

Tags: rust

**Project structure is as -**

[image]

and **foo.rs** is as-

```
pub mod Foo {
    pub fn work() {
        println!("Test executed.");
    }
}
```

**main.rs** is simple as -

```
fn main() {
    
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

now how to call `work` function in `main` function?

I have tried with -

- use crates::modals::Foo; not working
- adding mod.rs in modals not working
- adding modals.rs at main.rs level not working

What are the right and simple ways to do this?

Comment: Is it "modals" or "models"?

Answer (score -1):

You also need a `src/lib.rs`:

```
pub mod modals;
```

Then a `src/modals/mod.rs` instead of `src/modals/foo.rs`, though you could have in that:

```
pub mod foo;
```

Then to import it into `main.rs`:

```
use cratename::modals::Foo;
```

Where `cratename` is the `name =` property in your `Cargo.toml`.

Unlike other more free-form languages, Rust has significant constraints on how you name and organize your files.

Comment: So in this case what will be main.rs code?

Comment: But with that statement I am getting unresolved import `crate::modals`

Comment: I have added lib.rs, mod.rs and kept foo.rs as it is.

Comment: Make sure you have a `mod.rs` in each "module" directory, and that your `Cargo.toml` defines a crate, which it might not.

Comment: No luck, refer this too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45519176/how-do-i-use-or-import-a-local-rust-file but no luck

Comment: Modules are declared starting at a crate entry point. Either `lib.rs` or `main.rs` can be an entry point but not both. You can make it work, but it is far more confusing and only necessary when you want the crate to be _both_ a binary and a library.