# How to import diesel models and schema?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-diesel, rust-crates

I'm trying to create a small demo app using the diesel crate.
I tried the things below by looking at [the diesel getting started guide](http://diesel.rs/guides/getting-started/).

I don't understand how to import my models and schema and get my query working in main. Attached the snapshot shows project structure with that import error.

Here are my files:

**schema.rs**

```
table! {
    department (dept_id) {
        dept_id -> Int4,
        dept_name -> Nullable<Text>,
        created_on -> Nullable<Timestamp>,
        created_by -> Nullable<Text>,
        modified_on -> Nullable<Timestamp>,
        modified_by -> Nullable<Text>,
        is_active -> Nullable<Bool>,
    }
}
```

**models.rs**

```
#![allow(unused)]
#![allow(clippy::all)]


use chrono::NaiveDateTime;
use bigdecimal::BigDecimal;
#[derive(Queryable, Debug, Identifiable)]
#[primary_key(dept_id)]
pub struct Department {
    pub dept_id: i32,
    pub dept_name: Option<String>,
    pub created_on: Option<NaiveDateTime>,
    pub created_by: Option<String>,
    pub modified_on: Option<NaiveDateTime>,
    pub modified_by: Option<String>,
    pub is_active: Option<bool>,
}
```

**lib.rs**

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate diesel;
extern crate dotenv;

use diesel::prelude::*;
use dotenv::dotenv;
use std::env;

pub fn establish_connection() -> PgConnection {
    dotenv().ok();

    let database_url = env::var("DATABASE_URL").expect("DATABASE_URL must be set");
    PgConnection::establish(&database_url)
        .unwrap_or_else(|_| panic!("Error connecting to {}", database_url))
}
```

**cargo.toml**

```
[dependencies]
diesel = { version = "1.4.5", features = ["postgres"] }
dotenv = "0.15.0"
chrono = { version = "0.4.19" , features = ["serde"] }
bigdecimal = { version = "0.2.0" }
```

**main.rs**

```
use diesel_app::establish_connection;

fn main() {
    use diesel_app::schema::department::dsl::*;

    let con = establish_connection();
    let result = department
        .limit(2)
        .load::<Department>(&con)
        .expect("Error loading department");
}
```

I tried looking at the resources given by rust but did not understand much. 
Can anybody tell me how to resolve these imports and get my query working ? 
Where am I going wrong ? 
[image: Here is the import error]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I "use" or import a local Rust file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45519176/how-do-i-use-or-import-a-local-rust-file) or perhaps [Rust package with both a library and a binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26946646/rust-package-with-both-a-library-and-a-binary)

Comment: @kmdrekoIt does helpful but when I added "mod models;" and "mod schema;" in main.rs then it's giving me this error "couldn't read src\models.rs: stream did not contain valid UTF-8". 
As per the link which you have provided, my scenario is about "Including" internal code. Why I am still getting error !!!

Comment: That sounds to me like the next error. Might your files not be UTF-8 encoded? (tbh I'm not even sure if that's required, but that'd be the next thing I'd look at).

Comment: The above link given by @kmdreko has worked for me. It was a problem with vs code rust extension. I upgraded that and error went.  Thank you everyone!!