# Rust tests fail to even run

Tags: unit-testing, rust, rust-cargo

I'm writing a project to learn how to use Rust and I'm calling my project [future-finance-labs](https://github.com/jinhale/future-finance-labs/tree/master). After writing some basic functions and verifying the app can be built I wanted to include some tests, located in `aggregates/mod.rs`. [The tests are in the same file as the actual code as per the documentation.] I'm unable to get the tests to run despite following the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-00-testing.html) to the best of my ability. I have tried to build the project using PowerShell as well as Bash. [It fails to run on Fedora Linux as well]

Here is my output on Bash:

```
~/future-finance-labs$ cargo test -- src/formatters/mod.rs
    Finished test [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 5.98s
     Running target/debug/deps/future_finance_labs-16ed066e1ea3b9a1

running 0 tests

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out
```

Using PowerShell I get the same output with some errors like the following:

```
error: failed to remove C:\Users\jhale\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\home\jhale\future-finance-labs\target\debug\build\mime_guess-890328c8763afc22\build_script_build-890328c8763afc22.build_script_build.c22di3i8-cgu.0.rcgu.o: The system cannot find the path specified. (os error 3)
```

After my initial excitement at the prospect of writing a few tests that passed on the first attempt, I quickly realized all the green was indicative; rather, of a failure to even run the tests. I just want to run the unit tests. Running `cargo test` alone without a separate and file fails as well. Why can't I run any test in this project with my current setup?

Comment: It's `cargo test --test <test_name>` if I got your question right.

Comment: @Mihir, that gives me an error, which is more useful than simply not running the tests with no explanation. `$ cargo test --test src/aggregates/mod.rs 
error: no test target named src/aggregates/mod.rs`

Comment: I edited the question to make it clear that I have the test module in the same file as the code it tests, which the documentation seems to recommend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can't find your test because the rust compiler doesn't know about it. You need to add `mod aggregates` to main.

```
mod aggregates;

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

After you do that, you'll see that your `aggregates/mod.rs` doesn't compile for many reasons.

---

And as Mihir was trying to say, you need to use the name of the *test*, not the name of the *file* to run a specific test:

```
cargo test min_works
cargo test aggregates
```

See also:

- [How do I “use” or import a local Rust file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45519176/how-do-i-use-or-import-a-local-rust-file)
- [Rust Book: Controlling How Tests Are Run](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-02-running-tests.html)